# Can freetextbox display links that were not explicitly added?

Tags: asp.net, freetextbox

I would like to display links that are pasted in as links rather than text but freetextbox does not seem to do this. For instance, if somebody pastes in http://www.stackoverflow.com it looks like a link but shows up only as text. Do I need to convert this myself or is there a setting in the editor to take care of this?

Answer (score 0):

It depends.  In most cases, you need to convert it yourself.  Sometimes when you copy a link you are actually getting a link and not just the text.  But yes, you'll have to get your hands dirty here.

Comment: I think freetextbox might be encoding the link because even if I decode the text and it appears to be a valid link, when I view source it still looks like it is encoded. Although it does not appear to be encoded when using firebug/developer tools.

Comment: I am pretty sure I don't have freetextbox configured correctly. In firebug, I can drag a working link into the textbox and it will not work.

Comment: I am not sure what dragging a link in firebug does... In fact, my knowledge of FreeTextBox is woefully out of date, but I definitely don't remember the functionality you are asking about.  You'll have to write a little custom js for this, I think.

Comment: I think it just moves the markup to the new location. Creating a link through the freetextbox ui also does not work so I am pretty sure it is related to the control.